# How can I delete a specific element in priority queue?

Tags: java, priority-queue

```
import java.util.*;

public class test4 {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    PriorityQueue[] P = new PriorityQueue[10];
    P[1] = new PriorityQueue<ClassEntry>();
    P[1].add(new ClassEntry(1.2,1));
    P[1].add(new ClassEntry(1.5,2));
    P[1].add(new ClassEntry(1.2,3));
    P[1].add(new ClassEntry(10,4));

    P[1].remove(new ClassEntry(10,4));//I can't delete this object???

    System.out.println(P[1].size());
    ClassEntry ce = (ClassEntry) P[1].peek();
    System.out.println(P[1].size());
    System.out.println(ce.sim+"\t"+ce.index);
  }
}
```

Why i can't delete (10,4)? Can somebody teach how to implement...thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ClassEntry` has to override and implement `Object.equals(Object o)` for remove to work. For example:

```
class ClassEntry{
  float a;
  int b;

  public ClassEntry(float a, int b){
    //...
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o instanceof ClassEntry){
      ClassEntry c = (ClassEntry)o;
      return a == c.a && b == c.b;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

EDIT: As was kindly pointed out by @Jim Garrison, if you do not implement equals the default behaviour, which is to compare objects by reference, is used. In this case for your code to work you will need to remove like this:

```
PriorityQueue[] P = new PriorityQueue[10];
P[1] = new PriorityQueue<ClassEntry>();
ClassEntry entry = new ClassEntry(10,4);
P[1].add(entry);
//remove object with the same reference as the added one
P[1].remove(entry);
```

Comment: +1 with a clarification: the queue has to know how to determine if two objects are "equal" in order to find the one you want to delete.  If you don't provide code to implement the "equal" criteria you are interested in, you get the default `equals()` from `java.lang.Object`, which compares the object addresses in memory.

Comment: thank you! but i don't know how can i let equals function works? Should i call equals() in test4 class?

Comment: `equals` just needs to be implemented by `ClassEntry` class. You don't need to call it. `PriorityQueue` will use it when you call `remove` function.

Comment: but i found that return a == o.a && b == o.b; will be error, since o is not an classEntry object? thank you:)

Comment: Actually instanceof return false if o == null, so it's not needed to check it for null. And of course you need to cast Object o to ClassEntry when you try to compare a and b variables.

Comment: @Yuan. Sorry, there was a small bug. `o` needs to be casted to `ClassEntry` before checking. I have updated my code.